# Where can I find NIST SP800-38E's Test vectors?

Tags: nist

I am implementing XTS-AES mode in NIST SP800-38E, But I didn't find test vectors about it.

Who can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test vectors, as well as the requirements for validation testing, are currently available here:

https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/cryptographic-algorithm-validation-program/CAVP-TESTING-BLOCK-CIPHER-MODES

By the way, this was literally the first result for a google search of "XTS-AES test vectors"

Comment: Thanks, I need it.

Comment: Would you mind and paste one or two here in case NIST decides to move it or gets shutdown (again)?